# Counting without foreach

Tags: php, count

While I know how to create a counting inside a foreach,

```
$i = -1;
foreach ($menu_items as $item => $value) :
    ...
$i--;       
endforeach;
```

I want to create the same counting effect but my own code isn't inside a foreach. A sample of my code is like this:

```
<ul>
<li>...</li>
<li class="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr( $count ); ?>]">...</li>
<li class="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr( $count ); ?>]">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr( $count ); ?>]"></li>
        <li class="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr( $count ); ?>]"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr( $count ); ?>]">...</li>
</ul>
```

Outcome should be like this.

```
<ul>
<li>...</li>
<li class="menu-item[-1]">...</li>
<li class="menu-item[-2]">...</li>
<li class="menu-item[-3]">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-item[-4]"></li>
        <li class="menu-item[-5]"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item[-6]">...</li>
</ul>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not have a function that returns the current `$count` value, and increments it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
<ul>
<li>...</li>
<li class="menu-item[<?php $count = -1; echo esc_attr( $count ); ?>]">...</li>
<li class="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr( --$count ); ?>]">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr( --$count ); ?>]"></li>
        <li class="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr( --$count ); ?>]"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr( --$count ); ?>]">...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! Both yours and RiggsFolly answer have been very helpful. Yours is choosen as the answer due to `$count = -1;` which makes your answer more complete.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to decrement the counter as you go along with the `--`

Start by setting `count` to zero or whatever you want the counter to start at, as you have just before your `foreach` loop.

```
<ul>
<li>...</li>
<li class="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr( $count-- ); ?>]">...</li>
<li class="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr( $count-- ); ?>]">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr( $count-- ); ?>]"></li>
        <li class="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr( $count-- ); ?>]"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr( $count-- ); ?>]">...</li>
</ul>
```

This will decrement the `$count` field AFTER displaying its current value.

If you were to use

```
<li class="menu-item[<?php echo esc_attr( --$count ); ?>]">...</li>
```

it would decrement the counter first and then display its value.